# How to reset radio button on click reset button in Angular2+?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

My HTML code:

```
 <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right filter-dropdown-menu  row">
     <input type="radio" class="filter-dropdown-menu-padding" (click)="filter_source_type(0)" name="gender" value="male"> Admin
     <input type="radio" class="filter-dropdown-menu-padding" (click)="filter_source_type(1)" name="gender" value="male"> Manager
     <input type="radio" class="filter-dropdown-menu-padding" (click)="filter_source_type(2)" name="gender" value="male"> Member<br>

 </div>
```

Reset HTML code:

```
<div class="btn btn-primary btn-reset" (click)="reset_filter()">Reset</div>
```

My ts code for reset:

```
reset_filter() {
this.filter_source_type_value =null;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ngModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) for resetting radio button by assigning value `null`

**Do this in your HTML code:**

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right filter-dropdown-menu row">
   <input type="radio" #radio class="filter-dropdown-menu-padding" 
   [(ngModel)]="gender" (click)="filter_source_type(0)" name="gender"
   value="male"> Admin
   <input type="radio" #radio class="filter-dropdown-menu-padding" 
   [(ngModel)]="gender" (click)="filter_source_type(1)" name="gender" 
   value="female"> Manager
   <input type="radio" #radio class="filter-dropdown-menu-padding" 
   [(ngModel)]="gender" (click)="filter_source_type(2)" name="gender" 
   value="other"> Member
   <br>
</div>
<div class="btn btn-primary btn-reset" (click)="reset_filter()">Reset</div>
```

**Do this in your .ts(component) code:**

```js
export class AppComponent {
    gender = null; // Declared property with default `null` value

    /**
     * This function is used to reset radio buttons
     */
    reset_filter() {
        this.gender = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked on chrome! Thanks. But I'm still getting the radio button as selected in Safari. They are not resetting

Comment: I used something exactly same as your code but it wasn't working on Safari mobile. So, I used a div and shaped it like my radio buttons. and that fixed my problem.

Comment: @Mahin Khan The above code should work in Safari too. If you can create stackblitz, that would be great to check your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code in your HTML.

```
[(ngModel)]="filter_source_type_value"
```

Note: Your radio value should not be same. As per your code it should be like Admin, Manager, Member.

Comment: yes i am using radio button for filter in role wise. and how to use [(ngModel)] in multiple radio button input ?